# Netty channelRead is not getting invoked while waiting response from Oracle DB server over SSL

Tags: oracle, ssl, netty

In my project, a Java client program tries to connect an Oracle DB server over SSL with Netty.

the client simply sends the connection string to DB server and waits the response (TCPS packets).

my code snippets are given below:

```
....

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextFactory.getSslClient();
SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
engine.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1"});
engine.setUseClientMode(true);
socketChannel.pipeline().addFirst("ssl",new SslHandler(engine));

....
```

In my handler class that extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter, I see that ssl handshake and peer authentication is completed successfully.

In addition to this,

```
ctx.channel().read();
```

line has been reached in the following method:

```
@Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.read();

        if (message != null) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer((byte[]) message)).addListener((ChannelFutureListener) (channelFuture) -> {
                if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
                    ctx.channel().read();
                } else {
                    channelFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
                    channelFuture.channel().close();
                }
            });

            message = null;
        }
    }
```

however, **channelRead** method is never called and DB server doesn't send any data.

I will be happy if You have any suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.... if the DB server doesn't send any data you will never have channelRead(...) be called (as there is no data to dispatch).

Comment: @NormanMaurer thanks. I think everything about Netty ssl config is ok, therefore I should focus on behaviour of Oracle DB server.